# 128 bit timestamp in NTP queries

Tags: ntp

Wikipedia claims that NTPv4 supports 128-bit timestamps and indeed [RFC5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905) defines a 128-bit format called "NTP Date Format" in [Sect. 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905#section-6). The RFC says

> The 128-bit date format is used where sufficient storage and word
> size are available.

However, when I send 128-bit timestamps to public NTP servers, there is no response. Furthermore, [Sect. 7.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905#section-7.3) defines all four timestamp fields to be 64-bit. To avoid Y2k38 bugs, I want to implement NTP properly using 128-bit timestamps. How can I get a server to respond with full 128-bit timestamps?

Comment: ntpdate seems to do it: `reference time:    e1d49463.09878698  Thu, Jan 23 2020 22:53:39.037
originate timestamp: e1d49469.1247687f  Thu, Jan 23 2020 22:53:45.071
transmit timestamp:  e1d49469.0d789064  Thu, Jan 23 2020 22:53:45.052
`

Comment: No, those are 64-bit timestamps (32 bit integer and 32 bit fractional, both 8 hex digits). The 128-bit format has 64-bit integer and 64-bit fractional.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I stumbled here looking for the same thing. Page 13 of RFC5905 details that the expanded v4 format still contains a 32-bit value for seconds, but a signed 32-bit value for the era number. The seconds field in 128-bit date format is the offset within the era, so can handle dates far beyond 136 years. Seconds from prime epoch (1970) = era*(2^32) + era_offset(32bit seconds).